# Are there any alternatives to LaTeX that feel more like HTML?

Tags: mathematical-software, latex, software

so I’ll preface this with I’m pretty familiar with HTML and enjoy using it quite a bit. I’m looking for a way to write maths and essays with a language similar to HTML if that’s even possible.

Comment: I would say that the logical structure of LaTeX is quite similar to that of HTML.

Comment: [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)?  Of course that's very heavyweight.  I'm sure you could come up with a processor to turn `<inline>x<sup>2</sup></inline>` into `\(x^2\)` if you really wanted to, but is the former really easier to author?

Comment: I have the impression that ConTeXt is a bit closer to HTML than LaTeX is. ConTeXt has an emphasis on defining and using structured *environments*, called "descriptions" in ConTeXt, rather than defining and using *commands* as is common in LaTeX. This is perhaps analogous to what CSS gives you, on top of HTML. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt

Comment: I have no idea if it is "more like HTML than LaTeX" but I know that Dan Romik has been developing another markup language for writing mathematical documents called MadHat: see https://madhat.design/